# Editing only imported records in table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

```
Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
f.AllowMultiSelect = True
f.InitialFileName = "S:\Formware\outfile\ucppt12\Storage"
f.Filters.Clear
f.Filters.Add " Armored TXT Files", "*.asc"
    If f.Show Then
    For Each varItem In f.SelectedItems
        strFile = Dir(varItem)
        strFolder = Left(varItem, Len(varItem) - Len(strFile))
        P = strFolder & strFile
        DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "UCPP Import Specification", "ucppltr", P, False

    Next
    End If
strUpdate = "PARAMETERS fileName Text;" & vbCrLf & _
"UPDATE ucppltr" & vbCrLf & _
"Set [File Name] = fileName"
Debug.Print strUpdate
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", strUpdate)

'Pass file list to query
qdf.Parameters("fileName") = strFile

qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
Set qdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
Set f = Nothing
```

As you can see I am importing a text file normally around 5-6 at a time using `MultiSelect` . I have a field for file name and would like to populate it based on the file the records were imported from. So far mine only overwrites the first 4 or 5 with the last ones file name giving all the records the same file name. I am unsure if there is a way to populate the field on import via `TransferText` or any other ways for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `UPDATE` statement to include `WHERE [File Name] Is Null`.

Then, immediately after each `TransferText`, feed the current file name to the `UPDATE` query and execute it.

```vb
strUpdate = "PARAMETERS fileName Text;" & vbCrLf & _
    "UPDATE ucppltr" & vbCrLf & _
    "Set [File Name] = fileName" & vbCrLf & _
    "WHERE [File Name] Is Null;"
Debug.Print strUpdate
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", strUpdate)

Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
f.AllowMultiSelect = True
f.InitialFileName = "S:\Formware\outfile\ucppt12\Storage"
f.Filters.Clear
f.Filters.Add " Armored TXT Files", "*.asc"
If f.Show Then
    For Each VarItem In f.SelectedItems
        strFile = Dir(VarItem)
        strFolder = Left(VarItem, Len(VarItem) - Len(strFile))
        p = strFolder & strFile
        DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, _
            "UCPP Import Specification", "ucppltr", p, False
        'Pass file name to the query
        qdf.Parameters("fileName") = strFile
        qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
    Next
End If
```